# How to mask last 2 parts of an IP?

Tags: firewall, ip

This maybe a dumb question but I want to block all IPs in my firewall starting with `149.129.xx.xx`. I'm not able to figure out what to enter in my firewall setting. The field asks me for IP/Netmask and by default sets it to `/32`.

So If I enter `149.129.0.0`, it makes it `149.129.0.0/32`. I know how to mask the last part of the IP using `149.129.47.0/24` but I can't understand how it works. What would be the equivalent mask if I want to cover last 2 parts of the IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `149.129.0.0/16`